# Infinite loop in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char _char = 32;
    int x, p, i, d;
    scanf("%d ", &x);
    while(_char == 32)
        _char = getchar();
    x = x%26;
    printf("The encrypted string is: ");
    while((_char >= 'a' && _char <= 'z') || (_char >= 'A' && _char <= 'Z'))
    {
        if(_char >= 'a' && _char <= 'z')
            _char = 'a' + (_char + x - 'a')%26;
        else
            _char = 'A' + (_char + x - 'A')%26;
        d = 'a' - 'A';
        p = (_char >= 'a') ? _char - d : _char + d;
        printf("%c", p);
        scanf("%c", &_char);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code description : the program receives a number 'x' followed by spaces and then a sequence of letters , then it will print these letters (modified) until the first number or when there is no more letters to receive . It works fine when I run it in Code blocks but when I use CMD to insert the inputs as a file , this gives me an infinite loop if I insert :

```
1   FffF
```

when I add 0 or any number it works fine :

```
1   FffF0
```

the infinite loop is sth like :

The encrypted string is: 
`BBBcccDDDeeefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz....`

how can I slove this !?

Comment: A small tip: Instead of doing comparison like you do in the `while` condition to check for a letter, there is a handy function called `isalpha`. There is also functions to check if characters are lower- or upper-case: `islower` and `isupper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no more input to scan,

```
 scanf("%c", &_char);
```

doesn't modify `_char`. You have to check the return value of the scan,

```
if (scanf("%c",&_char) < 1) break;
```

to exit the loop then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the return value of `scanf`, so you don't detect that the input has ended. Scanf returns number of matched items, which is 1 in your case when successful. When end-of-file is reached before the first item, it returns -1.

So you should `break` of the loop when `scanf` doesn't return 1.